# Compare a string with current time

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a string with a specific hour-minut timestamp like this:

```
let timeToday = "14:00"
```

and I want to compare this time to the current time of the current day. I'm having problems with NSDate and the fact that it uses a UTC timestamp. I havn't used `NSDate`, `NSCalendar` or `NSDateFormatter` before, and I'm a bit frustrated over how dificult it is to solve this seemingly simple task...

So I was trying to set both the same time from the string and the current time, into two NSDate variables, and then use some sort of compare method, but i can't seem to get them on the same basis.

**How can get the two timestamps on the same basic?**

so the I have a NSDate with:

```
NSDate: timeToday     // "2015-12-05 14:00:00 +0000"
NSDate: currentTime   // "2015-12-05 22:46:54 +0000"
```

Comment: +0000 means UTC time

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. At first I thought you were saying that you wanted to treat time strings that look like "14:00" as if they are times in the current day and current user's time zone. In that case you'd create an NSDateFormatter and feed it the format string "HH:mm" and simply convert time strings to date using `dateFromString()`. You could use the same date formatter to display the current date to a time string, this time using `stringFromDate()`

Comment: You're going to need to bite the bullet and read up on NSDate, NSDateFormatter, NSCalendar, and especially the section in the docs on NSCalendar on "calendrical calculations." That section is really helpful. This stuff is complex and a little confusing and requires fairly deep study in order to "[**grok**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=grok)" it.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up reading through the documentation to understands the conpects of the datatypes. `NSDate` represents a point in time, which will be displayed differently depending on where you are on the globe. So using the UTC as the basis for both the time string and the current time is totally fine.

I solved the problem like this, using :

```
let calender = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
calender!.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()

let timeToday = "14:00"
let timeArray = timeToday.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
let timeTodayHours = Int(timeArray[0])
let timeTodayMin = Int(timeArray[1])
let timeTodayDate = calender!.dateBySettingHour(timeTodayHours!, minute: timeTodayMin!, second: 00, ofDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions())

let now = NSDate()
if now.compare(timeTodayDate!) == .OrderedDescending {
    print(" 'timeToday' has passed!!! ")
}
```

Comment: You can also try to use NSDateComponents and set the hour on it.